# Radio button for boolean property

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a simple boolean property `valid` in my object `document`
and need to bind it to radio-inputs.

This is what I have so far:

```html
<input type="radio" name="valid" id="validTrue" (click)="document.valid = true" [checked]="document.valid"/>
<input type="radio" name="valid" id="validFalse" (click)="document.valid = false" [checked]="!document.valid"/>
```

At least setting the property on click works but its state is not displayed by the radio-inputs. Looking in the developer console of my browser I found out that a property `ng-reflect-checked` is set but it doesn't seem to have impact on the HTML radio-input.

What am I doing wrong?
Does anyone have a working "angular2-boolean-radio-input" snippet?

Comment: which angular 2 version you are using

Comment: New RC.3 forms or deprecated forms?

Comment: Sorry... i am on rc3 using the new forms.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

In the new forms module this might do what you want

```html
  <input type="radio" name="food" [(ngModel)]="document.valid" [value]="true">
  <input type="radio" name="food" [(ngModel)]="document.valid" [value]="false">
```

see also  [design doc for the new forms module](https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1RIezQqE4aEhBRmArIAS1mRIZtWFf6JxN_7B4meyWK0Y/pub)

Comment: Your're right. It is that simple. I think i already tried this but forget to put the vale attribute in square brackets.

Comment: Without the `[]` you get `true` and `false` as string which I guess are both the value `true` in JS/TS (not sure, I don't use it much)

Comment: Bear in mind that if you change to ReactiveForms then you have to remove the [] around value, since valueChanges is what you subscribe to in a RF form (so you cannot bind it also). Easy to forget the difference between the two types of forms.

Comment: And if you want ReactiveForms Radio buttons see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956579/angular2-reactive-forms-formcontrol-for-radio-buttons

Comment: I've tried to do this but my radio buttons become unchecked. I need the one setted up with true value to load as checked by default, while the other one stay unchecked. How could I activate this behavior?

Comment: If you change the value of `document.valid` between `true` and `false`, the radio should switch as well.

Comment: This solution only works if you have exactly 2 radio buttons. Is there a way to just get the `checked` boolean property, rather than evaluating the `value` property?

Comment: Value can also be something else than `true` and `false`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer "Without the [] you get true and false as string which I guess are both the value true in JS/TS (not sure, I don't use it much"  **So, what's the difference between value = "false" vs value = "'false'" ?** - Notice the extra quotes in the latter case.

Comment: With `[value]="false"` you bind the boolean literal `false` to the value property of the element and the `@Input() value:boolean;` of the directive/component. If such a property or input doesn't exist an exception is thrown. With `value="false"` you bind the string `"false"` to the `value` attribute. If the HTML element supports such an attribute it might convert it to boolean and assign the value to its property. If a directive/component is hosted on that element the string will be assigned to it `value` input. The inputs gets a `string` value passed.

Comment: @DarionN If you use `value` then normal attribute binding is used, which passes values always as string. With `[value]` it becomes a property binding that passes all values as original types. With `[]` the part in `"..."` is interpreted as code and `true` is passed as boolean value, while with `value="true"` `"true"` is passed as string. In JS `"false"` is also truthy, so with a string value this can not work.