# Have a mat-radio-button in a ngFor work with Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms, ngfor

I have been trying to use radio buttons from angular material with reactive forms while using a loo but with no success. I successfully used html native radio buttons but when I change to mat-radio-buttons, while selecting a value for the "second" control it will set that same value for the first one.

What am I doing wrong here? Demo below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-68mtq8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the form control from the `mat-radio-group` since you are assigning the value in a method `setAnswer(answer : any)` to the specific control, assigning a control to the group is not necessary.

```
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [formControlName]="ctrls[currentQuestion]">
```

change to this

```
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group">
```

**Revision**

Attempting to bind a form control to your `mat-radio-button` results in the following error.

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'func'

The reason for this is because `mat-radio-button` does not have a `ControlValueAccessor`directive and is why you were successful using native radio buttons.

> Form control directives use a ControlValueAccessor directive to
>   communicate with the native element. There are different types of
>   ControlValueAccessors for each of the possible inputs. The correct one
>   is chosen by the selector of the value accessor directive. The
>   selectors are based on what type the `<input>` is. When you have
>   type="radio", then the value accessor for radios will be used.

Explanation from this answer

[Angular2 Reactive Forms formControl for radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956579/angular2-reactive-forms-formcontrol-for-radio-buttons)

In this scenario, using a method to set the value on the control would be the correct approach... if you do not want to use the method to set the value on the formControl, you will need to use native html buttons as you did before.

**Revision 2**

Reading the last answer on that linked SO question further there appears to be a way to do this without using native HTML buttons.

- The key here is to iterate over your `ctrls` and create a
  `mat-radio-group` for each one.
- Then you must use an *ngIf to compare the `index` to the
  `currentQuestion` so that you only show the correct group based on
  `currentQuestion`

Please see HTML below.

```
<mat-card>
    <div id="questions-container">
        <div class="arrows" (click)="previousQuestion()">
            <div>
                <</div>
            </div>
            <div class="question-container">
                <form [formGroup]="form">

                    <h1>Question placeholder?</h1>
                    <div *ngFor="let ctrl of ctrls; let i = index">
                        <mat-radio-group *ngIf="currentQuestion == i" class="example-radio-group" [formControlName]="ctrl">
                            <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let answer of answers[currentQuestion]" [value]="answer.id">{{answer.label}}</mat-radio-button>
                        </mat-radio-group>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="arrows" (click)="nextQuestion()">
                <div>></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <p>{{currentQuestion}}</p>
        <p>{{ctrls[currentQuestion]}}</p>
        <pre>{{form.value | json}}</pre>

</mat-card>
```

Comment: Got it. Another question, is possible to get it to work with the other way, without using the event? Thanks

Comment: please see revision.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: seems there is a way to accomplish this using formcontrol on mat-radio-group.. please see revision2