# How to pass the value of a radio button in a reactive angular form?

Tags: angular

My Angular app has a radio button group whose selected value I want to pass onto a node.js server when the Submit button is clicked.

When I use this code:

TS:

```
ngOnInit(){
    insuredType: new FormControl('Private person', Validators.required),
}
```

HTML:

```
<radio-button-wrapper >
    <radio formControlName="insuredType" heading="Private person" value="Private person" data-orientation="inline" cid="Private person"
            name="Private person">
    </radio>

    <radio formControlName="insuredType" heading="Corporation" value="Corporation" data-orientation="inline" cid="Corporation"
            name="Corporation">
    </radio>
</radio-button-wrapper>
```

The default selected radio button is Private person.
If I don't change that, & send the form, "Private person" is sent as expected.

But, if I select the *Corporation* radio button, then **[Object object]** is sent rather than *Corporation*.

Also, if I update my ngOnInit() to this:

```
ngOnInit(){
    insuredType: new FormControl(Validators.required),
}
```

And select one of the radio buttons, **[Object object]** is sent.

Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong here, I want to know how I can pass the value of the radio button.

Finally, this is the form which it is part of :

```
<form [formGroup]="emailForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(emailForm.value)"</form>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you try to put `formControlName` on each radio instead ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956579/angular2-reactive-forms-formcontrol-for-radio-buttons

Comment: Hi @ArnaudDenoyelle I added `formControlName="insuredType"`. Now, regardless of which radio button I select, **Private person** is being sent. So if I choose _Corporation_, **Private person** is still being sent.

Comment: Did you also remove `formControlName` from `<radio-button-wrapper>` ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Yes, I did. I have updated my code above to reflect. Regardless of which radio button is chosen, **Private person** is sent every time.

Comment: Can you try `[formControl]="insuredType"` instead of `formControlName="insuredType"` ? (on each radio)