# Created custom radio button library, but did not check radio button while binding with reactive-form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-library

Angular library
I am trying to created a library for custom radio button with its role like warning(color yellow dot) error(color red dot) info(color blue dot) and success(color green dot) without angular library it will work fine, After that I move my css and template to library but now it is not work is expected

I have provide value from reactive from but it does not check as expect I have also added screenshot at the end what I am expecting and what I get currently

**radio-button.html**

```
    <label class="container" >
        <input type="radio" #radioButton [name]="lbName" (click)="onClick($event)" [value]="lbValue"  
                                              [disabled]="lbDisabled" />
        <span [class]="className"></span>
        <span>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </span>
    </label>
```

**radio-button.scss**

```
/* The container */
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.lb-radio {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container input ~ .lb-radio--warning {
    border: 1px solid darkorange;
}

.container input ~ .lb-radio--success {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.container input ~ .lb-radio--error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.container input ~ .lb-radio--info {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.container input[type='radio']:checked ~ .lb-radio--warning {
    background-color: darkorange;
}

.container input[type='radio']:checked ~ .lb-radio--success {
    background-color: green;
}

.container input[type='radio']:checked ~ .lb-radio--error {
    background-color: red;
}

.container input[type='radio']:checked ~ .lb-radio--info {
    background-color: blue;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.lb-radio::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container .lb-radio::after {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container input[type='radio']:checked ~ .lb-radio::after {
    display: block;
}

.container input[type='radio']:disabled + span {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.container input[type='radio']:disabled ~ span {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: none;
    color: grey;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.container input[type='radio']:checked:disabled + span {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: grey;
}

.container input[type='radio']:checked:disabled ~ span {
    background-image: none;
    color: grey;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

**radio-button.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import { coerceBooleanProperty } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'lb-radio-button, [lb-radio-button]',
    templateUrl: './radio-button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./radio-button.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => RadioButtonComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class RadioButtonComponent implements OnInit,  ControlValueAccessor {
    @ViewChild('radioButton') radioButton: ElementRef;
    className = 'lb-radio';
    value = '';
    isDisabled: boolean;
    @Output() checkBoxClick: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    @Input() lbRole = 'info';
    @Input() lbName = 'radioButton';

    @Input()
    set lbDisabled(value: boolean) {
        this.isDisabled = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
    }
    get lbDisabled() {
        return this.isDisabled;
    }

    @Input()
    set lbValue(value: string) {
        this.writeValue(value);
        this.onChange(value);
        this.onTouched();
    }

    get lbValue(): string {
        return this.value;
    }

    onChange: any = () => {};
    onTouched: any = () => {};

    ngOnInit() {
        this.className += ` lb-radio--${this.lbRole}`;
    }

    onClick($event): boolean {
        if (this.lbDisabled) {
            return false;
        }
        this.writeValue($event.target.value);
        this.checkBoxClick.emit($event.target.value);
    }

    registerOnChange(fn) {
        this.onChange = fn;
      }

      writeValue(value) {
        if (value)
          this.value = value;
      }

      registerOnTouched(fn) {
        this.onTouched = fn;
      }
}
```

And used the library but male radio button does not checked as expected

```
**implementation.html**

<form [formGroup]="radioButtonForm">
    <p lb-radio-button [lbValue]="'Male'" [formControlName]="nameKey.gender" [lbRole]="'success'" [lbName]="'gender'">
       Male success radio button
    </p>
    <p lb-radio-button [lbValue]="'Female'" [formControlName]="nameKey.gender" [lbRole]="'info'" [lbName]="'gender'">
       Female info radio button
    </p>
    <div lb-button (buttonClick)="onSubmit()" type="submit" lbType="primary">Submit Form</div>
</form>

**implementation.ts**

export class RadioButtonComponent implements OnInit {
    radioButtonForm: FormGroup;

    nameKey =  {
        gender: 'gender',
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        this.radioButtonForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            gender: ['Male', Validators.required],
        });
    }

    onSubmit() {
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.radioButtonForm.value))
    }

}
```

**Expected**

[image]

Currently what I get

[image]

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sj9ntz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-button%2Fradio-button.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma624356536433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-button%2Fradio-button-group.ts) (the demo contains a little bit more information than the basics described in the suggestion below).

Using the same `FormControl` instance bound to several components is not something I'm comfortable with. If you allow me a suggestion which BTW **solves your problem with the initial value not being set in the `FormControl`**: why don't you leverage your component by creating a "RadioGroupControl" just to be used with forms, in such a way that you can associate a `FormControl` to the group, instead of doing it with individual controls.

What you could do:

### 1) Create a `LbRadioButtonGroupComponent`

Its template would be a very simple one:

```js
selector: 'lb-radio-group-control',
template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
```

As the selector says, this component is supposed to be used only for grouping radio-buttons inside forms. It should just work as a wrapper.

Inside its typescript, grab all the instances of the RadioButtons.

```js
@ContentChildren(RadioButtonComponent, { descendants: true })
_radioButtons: QueryList<RadioButtonComponent>;
```

Then subscribe to the event emitter inside each `RadioButtonComponent`. You'll need to emit more than just a boolean so that `LbRadioButtonGroupComponent` can set the right radio button `checked` state to `true` when you get an incoming value (set by the host with `setValue()`, `patchValue()`, or something like that). I suggest a `RadioButtonChange` property containing 2 attributes: `target` (the clicked `input`) and `value` (a convenience attribute, you can get rid of it if you want to). So we have:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const observableList: Observable<RadioButtonChange>[] = [];
  this._radioButtons.map((rb: RadioButtonComponent) => 
    observableList.push(rb.checkBoxClick));

  merge(...observableList)
    .pipe(
      filter(Boolean),
      takeUntil(this._destroy$)
    )
    .subscribe((value: any) => {
      this._onTouch();
      this._onChange(value ? value.value : null);
    });
}
```

Then we would need just a way to set up which button is currently checked. The problem here is just a matter of timing because we don't really know when the method is gonna be called to set a value and we must make sure that our `QueryList` was already executed and `this._radioButtons` is populated. Once we make sure that happened the following method should set the right radio button to `checked`:

```js
private _setGroupValue(value: any) {
  this._radioButtons.forEach(
    rb => (rb.radioButton.nativeElement.checked =
        rb.radioButton.nativeElement.value === value)
  );
}
```

### 2) Wrap your `RadioButtonComponent`s with `RadioButtonGroupComponent` when using them in a form as a group

Once we have these pieces in place, we can use our component like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="radioButtonForm">
  <lb-radio-group-control formControlName="gender">
    <p lb-radio-button [lbValue]="'Male'" 
                       [lbRole]="'success'">
      Male success radio button
    </p>
    <p lb-radio-button [lbValue]="'Female'" 
                       [lbRole]="'info'">
      Female info radio button
    </p>
  </lb-radio-group>
  <div lb-button (buttonClick)="onSubmit()" 
                 type="submit" 
                 lbType="primary">Submit Form</div>
</form>
```

As we already own the instances of `lb-radio-button`s, there's no need to set the name on them: we can do that in `LbRadioButtonGroupComponent`. Of course, you can do it in such a way that it doesn't matter if you set the name, or set different names to each radio button (by mistake).

[image]

### Side notes

In the code on Stackblitz, you'll find a more complete code, containing some validations, like a check to see whether inside the group there aren't any `RadioButtonComponent` bound to a `FormControl`, or whether the developer forgot to bind `LbRadioButtonGroupComponent` to a `FormControl`.

Well, this is just an overall idea to avoid binding the same `FormControl` to several components in the template. It's not complete and needs things like form validation, form control disabling, and ability to set the group value via an `@Input() value` (I started writing it in the demo, but I'm in a rush and I think you've already got the point).

Comment: @jullianobrasil why we are using setTime out on radio-group.ts and is value come from child component  to radio-group.ts (line number 39)

Comment: You're referring to the `set value(...)`, is that right? This is something I didn't have time to test, and its purpose is to give you the opportunity to set the value of the group by an input property. As the inputs are evaluated before during the `OnInit` life cycle, the `QueryList` will likely not be ready, so this is a precaution thinking of this case. I think we can get rid of it if we work around with a `Subject` instead of a `setTimeout` in this case. I'll take a look. Also, there's no need for `setTimeouti` in `AfterViewInit`. It's something I forgot to remove after the code was ready.

Comment: Oh, in fact, it was there to make sure angular had finished registering the functions of `ControlValueAccessor`. But it makes no sense since I'm initializing the `_onChange` with a dummy function and `this._onChange` will always be true. So I removed that part. But I introduced some logic for the `set value(...)` to override the value set via `FormControl` (I think it makes sense, in case of there's a race between the value entering into the component via the `FormControl` vs `set value(...)`.

Comment: I've changed my mind and stop setting `_onChange` to a dummy function before angular registering the real changing function. I did it because it made sense to me that the `FormControl` emitted something when the value entered the component via `set value(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't call writeValue inside lbValue setter, It will override the value set by FormControl.

```
@Input lbValue;
```

propagate value to parent Form you have to call stored onChange call back function, whenever custom control value changes.

```
 onClick($event): boolean {
        if (this.lbDisabled) {
            return false;
        }
        this.onChange($event.target.value);
        this.onTouched();
        this.checkBoxClick.emit($event.target.value);
    }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ryigwu)